# How to find the length of an array list?

Tags: java, arraylist

I don't know how to find the length of an array list. I think you might need to use `blank.length();` but I'm not sure.

I made an array list

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

but how do I write code to print out the size of myList?

Comment: int size = myList.size(); Pls try reading Javadoc and some tutorial on using Java collections.

Comment: [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#size()) is your friend!

Comment: It was probably more effort to ask the question here than to google it.

Comment: @Kyle: Ah, but then you don't get any ego-boosting SO reputation points.

Comment: @Kyle, also this question is now the top hit on google for "ArrayList length"

Comment: @Kyle: Much faster to google and read this post than to go through docs.

Comment: @Kyle - Hopefully you figured this out on your own in the past 4 years, but simple questions like this one often become the top result on Google years later. Their asking is hugely beneficial to future people searching for the answer (like myself).

Answer (score 272):

The size member function.

```
myList.size();
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: myList.size() gives actual no of elements in the list. Note that since indexing starts from 0, no of elements (according to indexing) will be size() - 1.

Answer (score 41):

```
System.out.println(myList.size());
```

Since no elements are in the list

> output  => 0

```
myList.add("newString");  // use myList.add() to insert elements to the arraylist
System.out.println(myList.size());
```

Since one element is added to the list

> output => 1