# Size has private access in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, private

I wrote a pretty standard bit of code utilizing String populated `ArrayList` but when I try running it, I get the following error:

`error: size has private access in ArrayList`.

The code is as follows:

```
System.out.println(testedArticles.size);
```

Comment: Please paste the complete code snippet

Comment: In all fairness the error is obvious with just the code at present

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652732/how-to-find-the-length-of-an-array-list/9652753#9652753

Comment: This question is basic, but I can imagine other people making this mistake and finding this question (especially as the error is quoted); such the mission of stack exchange is met. I think this is a good question despite the downvotes

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are attempting to access a private member of `ArrayList`, part of its internal working that are not supposed to be used externally

If you want to get the size of the arraylist you want the method:

```
arraylist.size()
```

### Why is it like this

This gives the `ArrayList` class the option to store size in whatever way it wants. Does it just return `size`, probably, but it could do a number of other things instead. For example it could calculate size lazily, in which it is only calculated if someone asked for it then it stores that value until it becomes invalid (as more objects are added). This would be useful if calculating size was expensive (very unlikely to be the case here), changed often and was called only occasionally.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing like  `ArrayList.size.` You need to use `.size()` method.

You need to use

```
System.out.println(testedArticles.size());
```

instead of

```
System.out.println(testedArticles.size);
```

Comment: He didn't say `.size.`