# Java ArrayList length error

Tags: java, arrays

Have method below that returns an array of all Lamborghini objects that have horsepower in the range passed as parameter. When I try to compile error at Lamborghini.length cannot find symbol - variable length. Isn't length part of ArrayList?

```
public Lamborghini[] getCarsWithHorsepowerRange(double lowHP, double highHP)
{

    int horsePower = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < Lamborghini.length; i++)
    {
        if(Lamborghini[i] != null)
        {
            if((Lamborghini[i].getHorsePower() >= lowHP) &&
            ((Lamborghini[i].getHorsePower() <= highHP)))
            {
                horsePower++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `Lamborghini`?

Comment: .size(), and you get the index by .get(i)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the length of an array list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652732/how-to-find-the-length-of-an-array-list)

Comment: Lamborghini is list or array? please write complete code . that will help to answer your question.

Comment: It is list, private ArrayList<Lamborghini> inventory;

Comment: @TOD from that declaration, it looks like `Lamborghini` is a class name, not the variable name (which is `inventory`), correct?

Comment: @resueman my constructor has                                                          inventory = new ArrayList<Lamborghini>(); to create the arraylist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few issues with your code. First off, you're trying to use `Lamborghini` to refer to the `ArrayList` you declared, when `Lamborghini` is just the type of object stored in it. Instead, you should use the variable name, in this case `inventory`, to refer to the instance of the `ArrayList` that you created.

Secondly, you're confusing [`Array`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) and [`ArrayList`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), which are different types, and have different ways to access their length and contents. Since you're using an `ArrayList`, you need to use the `size()` method to get its length, and the `.get(int)` method to access the elements.

So change your code to this to correct those errors:

```
public Lamborghini[] getCarsWithHorsepowerRange(double lowHP, double highHP){
    int horsePower = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < inventory.size(); i++){
        if(inventory.get(i) != null){
            if((inventory.get(i).getHorsePower() >= lowHP) &&
               (inventory.get(i).getHorsePower() <= highHP)){
                horsePower++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will still have a problem, since it has a return type of `Lamborghini[]` (an array of `Lamborghini`), which is never returned. I don't know what the intent is, but if you don't need the return value, you can just change the type to `void`. Or you could change the type to `ArrayList<Lamborghini>` and return the `inventory` object. Otherwise, you'll need to create a new array and populate it:

```
Lamborghini[] result = new Lamborghini[inventory.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < inventory.size(); i++){
    result[i] = inventory.get(i);
}
return result;
```

Comment: thanks resueman that was very helpful, thanks for clearly the Array S and ArrayList for me was going around in circles.

Answer (score 0):

lets say lamborghiniList is the list of Lamborghini object..
initialize it in constructor or by a setter method
you can try following code...

```
public Lamborghini[] getCarsWithHorsepowerRange(double lowHP, double highHP) {

    List<Lamborghini> desiredObjects = new ArrayList<Lamborghini>();

    for (int i = 0; i < lamborghiniList.size(); i++) {
        if (lamborghiniList.get(i) != null) {
            if ((lamborghiniList.get(i).getHorsePower() >= lowHP) &&
                    ((lamborghiniList.get(i).getHorsePower() <= highHP))) {
                desiredObjects.add(lamborghiniList.get(i));

            }
        }
    }
    return desiredObjects.toArray();
}
```