# ArrayList First Element finding

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am new to `Collection Framework`.i am running a java program using `ArrayList()`. When I am trying loop it to get the elements of it, but it is throwing error like

```
HelloWorld.java:15: error: cannot find symbol                                                                                                                                   
           for(int k=0;k<al.length;k++)                                                                                                                                         
                           ^                                                                                                                                                    
  symbol:   variable length                                                                                                                                                     
  location: variable al of type ArrayList<String>                                                                                                                               
HelloWorld.java:17: error: array required, but ArrayList<String> found                                                                                                          
             System.out.println("elements are"+al[k]);
```

here is the code i written.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HelloWorld{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
       al.add("pen");
       al.add("pencil");
       al.add("ink");
       al.add("notebook");
       al.add("book");
       al.add("books");
       al.add("paper");
       al.add("white board");

       for(int k=0;k<al.length;k++)
   {
         System.out.println("elements are"+al[k]);
  }
   }
}
```

help me to point out my error. thanks in advance

Comment: there is no length field in ArrayList, instead you need to do method call al.size()

Comment: arraylist has size property and not length

Comment: And then you can't use an indexer, you have to use `get`.

Comment: Use al.size() and al.get(k)

Comment: use `foreach` elegantly or `stream`

Answer (score 5):

The ArrayList has a method [`size`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9652745/4297364) that returns the size of the list, and a [`get`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3924759/4297364) method to get the element stored at a particular index.

So your for loop could look like:

```
for(int k=0; k < al.size(); k++) {
    System.out.println("elements are" + al.get(k));
}
```

Or if you want you could loop through each element without an index:

```
for(String text : al) {
    System.out.println("elements are" + text);
}
```

If you want to use `streams` with java8, you could also do:

```
al.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

If you are interested, there's another [answer that also talks about looping through lists in java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18410489/4297364).

Comment: Does it really work ? Indexing like `al[k]` on ArrayList should give some error ?

Comment: @SagarGautam Yes you are right. I edited the answer to use the `get` method. Thanks.

Comment: Or `System.out::println`

Comment: That's great Bro

Answer (score 3):

Since ArrayList is a collection not an array, you may use al.size() instead.

If you want to use index try this

```
al.get(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one You can't treat arrylist as array

```
for(int k=0;k<al.size();k++){
    System.out.println("elements are"+ al.get(k));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HelloWorld{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
       al.add("pen");
       al.add("pencil");
       al.add("ink");
       al.add("notebook");
       al.add("book");
       al.add("books");
       al.add("paper");
       al.add("white board");

       for(int k=0;k<al.size();k++)
       {
         System.out.println("elements are"+ al.get(k) );
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
al.add("pen");
al.add("pencil");
al.add("ink");
al.add("notebook");
al.add("book");
al.add("books");
al.add("paper");
al.add("white board");

for(int k=0;k<al.size();k++)
  {
      System.out.println("elements are"+al.get(k));
  }
```

You need to use `size()` in order to find out the `length` of `arraylist`
When you use Eclipse like Editors, hope you will overcome all these methods easily and also syntax errors itself help to learn properly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to Collection You confusing Array with Arraylist . Arraylist doesnot have length . It have `size()` method .

Since already good option given So go with java 8 [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
        al.add("pen");
        al.add("pencil");
        al.add("ink");
        al.add("notebook");
        al.add("book");
        al.add("books");
        al.add("paper");
        al.add("white board");

        al.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
     al.add("pen");
     al.add("pencil");
     al.add("ink");
     al.add("notebook");
     al.add("book");
     al.add("books");
     al.add("paper");
     al.add("white board");

     for(int k=0;k<al.size();k++)
      {
       System.out.println("elements are"+al.get(k));
      }
   }
}
```